# NJ has a 1-party consent, and MA a 2-party consent, for recording conversations. What if MA calls NJ?

Tags: united-states, privacy

I recorded a polling call and forgot to ask the person if it was OK to do so.

Massachusetts, where the company is located, has a two party consent law for recording.

http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/massachusetts-recording-law

New Jersey is one party consent.

http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/new-jersey/new-jersey-recording-law

So what the law when the person making the phone call is in Massachusetts, and the recorder/recipient is in New Jersey?

Comment: Depends upon who does the recording.

Comment: I'm in New Jersey. I did the recording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. On what? On how a judge feels on a given day.

That is to say, we are not sure.

Conventional wisdom says that we should be cautious and assume that the law of the stricter state will apply. But [some commentators](https://www.mwl-law.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/LAWS-ON-RECORDING-CONVERSATIONS-CHART.pdf) argue that the law of the state where the recording device is located should apply.

I found this discussion to be the most complete one-stop place for a nice summary. http://www.rcfp.org/reporters-recording-guide/interstate-phone-calls. I'm going to paste it here because I can and because SE likes that.

> Interstate phone calls   Date:  August 1, 2012   In light of the
>   differing state laws governing electronic recording of conversations
>   between private parties, journalists are advised to err on the side of
>   caution when recording or disclosing an interstate telephone call. The
>   **safest strategy is to assume that the stricter state law will appl**y.
>   For example, a reporter located in the District of Columbia who
>   records a telephone conversation without the consent of a party
>   located in Maryland would not violate District of Columbia law, but
>   could be liable under Maryland law. A **court located in the District of
>   Columbia may apply Maryland law**, depending on its “conflict of laws”
>   rules. Therefore, an aggrieved party may choose to file suit in either
>   jurisdiction, depending on which law is more favorable to the party’s
>   claim.   In one case, a New York trial court was asked to apply the
>   Pennsylvania wiretap law — which requires consent of all parties — to
>   a call placed by a prostitute in Pennsylvania to a man in New York.
>   Unlike the Pennsylvania wiretap statute, the New York and federal
>   statutes require the consent of only one party. The call was recorded
>   with the woman’s consent by reporters for The Globe, a national
>   tabloid newspaper. The **court ruled that the law of the state where the
>   injury occurred, New York, should apply**. (Krauss v. Globe
>   International)   The Supreme Court of California in Kearney v. Salomon
>   Smith Barney applied California wiretap law to a company located in
>   Georgia that routinely recorded business phone calls with its clients
>   in California. California law requires all party consent to record any
>   telephone calls, while Georgia law requires only one party consent.
>   The state’s high **court, applying choice of law principles, reasoned
>   that the failure to apply California law would “impair California’s
>   interest in protecting the degree of privacy afforded to California
>   residents by California law *more severely than* the application of
>   California law would impair any interests of the State of Georgia**.”
>   In another case involving Pennsylvania law, four employees of The
>   Times Leader, a newspaper in Wilkes-Barre, were arrested after they
>   printed a transcript of a telephone conversation between a columnist
>   in Pennsylvania and a murder suspect living in Virginia that was
>   recorded without the suspect’s permission. The Virginia and federal
>   statutes allow one party to record a conversation, while Pennsylvania,
>   as discussed above, requires the consent of all parties. The man asked
>   prosecutors to charge the journalists under the Pennsylvania law. The
>   court eventually dismissed the charges against the newspaper staff —
>   but on the unrelated ground that the suspect had no expectation of
>   privacy during his telephone interview with the columnist.
>   (Pennsylvania v. Duncan)   Federal law may apply when the conversation
>   is between parties who are in different states, although it is
>   unsettled whether a court will hold in a given case that federal law
>   “pre-empts” state law. In Duncan, the newspaper argued that the
>   federal law should pre-empt the state statutes, because the telephone
>   call crossed state lines, placing it under federal jurisdiction.
>   However, in that case, the court did not address the pre-emption
>   issue. Moreover, as noted above, either state may choose to enforce
>   its own laws.